# Появляется не весь сайт vue

Tags: vue.js, nginx, vds

Дорабатывал локально проект и всё было отлично, но вот пришло время залить его на сервак и случилась такая ситуация.
Отрисовалась только та часть которая разрабатывалась до меня, а все мои доработки (авторизация, регистрация, личный кабинет и т.д.) не отобразились. Может я что-то не верно сделал...я вообще без понятия( . Я новичок во вью и не могу разобраться пока что(
Структура приложения(если надо): [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
network от приложения:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Веб-сервер: nginx. Стучусь веб-сервером в директорию с проектом...вот что тут может быть не так? :\
Сам веб-сервер:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а вы его собрали?

Comment: Я написал npm run build, но в локальном проекте. Это имеет разницу?
Но написав это, я по прежнему имею эту проблему(

Comment: проблема решена. Нужно было подвести нжинкс не в корневую папку,а  в папку dist